# Call by reference or value while swift using method in C++

Tags: swift

Now, I am trying to create a high performance framework in C++, I know that I need to create .mm and .m wrapper to bridge swift and c++, which is fine; however, I am more concerned about memory management. Since I will create a special data structure in C++ and eventually I will ask swift to store in persistent storage. Therefore, I need to transfer the data between Swift and C++ (through objective-C).

My question is if I create all interfaces in C++ are pointers, can I assure that the data access by swift did not invoke any data copy? Or just simply refer to a pointer? I did not want to let memory allocation/copy to degrade the performance.

Comment: Swift is in some cases already faster than C/C++, it's cross platform and open source. So why still C++? If you implement all of Swift's language features like bound checks, reference counting, etc... in C++ then all the performance benefit is gone anyway. You can even manually memory manage Swift objects if you want. My suggestion - stick to 100% Swift. The only valid reason for C++ is having tons of legacy C++ code. I have done C++ for over ten years and would never ever trade it for Swift.

Comment: Thanks for your comments. You are right, I indeed have some legacy c++ code which already implemented, I just would like to reuse it. On the other hand, as I known, Swift is more like script language, does it still perform better than c++ if I use Swift to perform intensive computation (no framework is available to achieve my goal)? Thanks.

Comment: Swift looks like a scrpting language but it's blazingly fast. I have done some benchmarks where it even outperforms ANSI C. (e.g. sorting) But it really depends, some things are faster in C/C++ some are faster in Swift. But as a natively compiled language Swift is definitely in the same league like C/C++ and it's of course faster then Java. But as I said - if you implement the same language features in C++ you are on par. And: speed is not everything, productivity mothers also and here is Swift the clear Winner.Give it a try you will be surprised!